# transfer from http to https asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, http, https

Im trying to redirect a user once they logon to the secure part of my site.

Im currentlly using the

```
Response.Redirect(Request.Url.OriginalString.ToLower().Replace("http://", "https://"));
```

But the page just hangs then fails.

This is my first attempt at a https site so please be nice :)

How do i setup the site to accept https?

What am I doing wrong?
Sp

Comment: This isn't very clear. What's failing? Is the page being redirected?  Do you have your site set up to listen for SSL requests?

Comment: Can you post the failing code? Are you using a standard Response.Redirect or is this an MVC setup?

Comment: You haven't posted enough information for anyone to help you. All the code you've provided so far does is a string replacement. How are you using the result of this? Response.Redirect? Server.Transfer? When you say "then fails" what exactly do you mean? Is an exception being thrown? If so, what exception and what line is causing it to be thrown?

Comment: Sorry this isnt clear, I shall update the post

Comment: I suspect it hangs because you're redirecting *every call*, regardless of whether it's already HTTPS or not.  You need an if statement (similar to what Ardman's posted) to make sure you don't just keep redirecting endlessly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.Host.CompareTo("https://yourwebsite") != 0)
{
    HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("https://yourwebsite" + Context.Request.Url.PathAndQuery);
}
```

Comment: How about testing `Request.IsSecureConnection` rather than doing a string comparison? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.issecureconnection.aspx